# make some menu links float right and other left

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code and CSS for a horizontal menu. It displays the links (boxes) from left to right floated to the left of the page.

What is the best way to make one of the links (boxes) display to float to the right of the page?

I have tried using float right with the below CSS copied as navigation-right and changed the HTML as needed but that did not work.

#### HTML

```
<div class="navigation-left">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">SAF</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">Acudetox</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.navigation-left {
    height:auto;
    list-style:none;
    margin-right:40px;
    display:inline;
}
.navigation-left li{
    width:200px;
    height:25px;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#666666;
    border:none;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}
.navigation-left li:hover{
    background-color:#f36f25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.navigation-left li a{
    font-family:Calibri, Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.navigation-left li.current {
    background-color:#F36F25;
}
.navigation-left li.current a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W2x5y/

Comment: _"make one of the links"_ which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyrvh/) what you wanted?

```
<div class="navigation-left" style="float:left">
<ul>
<li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">SAF</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="navigation-left">
<ul style="float:right; ">
<li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">Acudetox</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you might expect, a simple `float: right;` does the trick.

```
<div class="navigation-left">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li style="float: right"><a href="#">SAF</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Acudetox</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W2x5y/1/

Comment: More simple, way better solution!

Comment: Hey! Is there a way to make it shrink and have it in different lines in the mobile version?

Comment: Yes, a lot has happened since 2013, try looking up «css grid» and «media query» :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you'd have to target some of the li tags with a class if you wanted to do that. Plus you need to max the width of the containing ul in order to give it room to float on the right.

http://jsfiddle.net/W2x5y/2/

```
<div class="navigation-left">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SAF</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="#">Acudetox</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

ul {
    width: 100%;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the two navs are sufficient different to split them into two elements. Create two elements. Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q7e3M/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="navigation-left">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">SAF</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation-right">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">Acudetox</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to keep the same element: http://jsfiddle.net/Afxkt/1/

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">SAF</a></li>
    <li class="navigation-right"><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">Acudetox</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
.navigation li {
    float: left;
}
.navigation-right {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: You're right, misunderstood the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting questions.  I'm hoping this helps.

You should anchor the navigation-left and navigation-right to a navigation box itself.

html:

```
<div class="nav-box">
    <div class="nav-left">
        <ul>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right">
        <ul>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body .nav-box {

    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background:#eee;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.nav-box .nav-left {
    display:inline;
    left:0;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
}
.nav-box .nav-right {
    display:inline;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    float:right;
    width:auto;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/VA7ya/1/

Answer (score 0):

**All at right side**

.right_side{ float:right}

```
<div class="navigation-left right_side">
<ul>
<li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">SAF</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>">Acudetox</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Last `<li>` to the right**

```
.navigation-left li:last-child{ float:right}
```

**first `<li>` to the right**

```
.navigation-left li:first-child{ float:right}
```

**second `<li>` to the right**

```
.navigation-left li:nth-last-child(2){ float:right}
```